# Mocking a function called within a function called within a function

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-mock

Let's say I have a file called `src/sample.py` which contains:

```
def c():
    return np.random.rand(10)
def b():
    return c() + 2
def a():
    return b() + 1
```

Then, in my `sample_test.py`, suppose in `test_a`, I want to mock the internal call to `c` inside of `b`. However, if I do:

```
def mocked_c():
    return np.repeat(1, repeats=10)

def test_a(mocker):
    mocker.patch('src.sample.c', mocked_c)
    assert np.all(a() == 5)
```

it won't actually mock the function `c`. However, since `b` is called directly in a, using `mocker.patch` on it will work as expected.

What's the correct way to mock `c` inside `test_a`?

Comment: You may need to call `start()` on the patcher that is returned by `patch()`, see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-methods-start-and-stop).

Comment: @metatoaster unfortunately I'm still receiving the same error.

Comment: Please update your question to include where you put the `start()` statement, and put a print statement or some kind of debugger statement inside `mocked_c` to ensure that is being called.  Your question is not complete enough and not simple enough as it depends on numpy, but I have expended the effort to verify that your assertion statement as is will fail.